# Visualization for showing 31 different combinations

Tags: info-visualisation, data-tables, charts, graphics

I have a dataset of customers and products they could have. There are a total of 5 different products (A,B,C,D,E). A customer can have any combination of the products, for example a customer can have just A or AB or ABC. So there are 31 total combinations that a customer can have.

Is there a graphic anyone can recommend to display all possible combinations and a count for each one? For example A - 20, AC - 50, etc.

The only option I could think of was a 31 x 31 matrix and use color to signify values. It will be a big table but at least it will show a high level view of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to just display the combination and number?

Have you tried a concentric ring graph (each ring being a product)? Example here: https://www.theguardian.com/world/interactive/2012/may/08/gay-rights-united-states Color in the spaces that represent owning a product and place the number on the outside of the ring (where the state is in the example).

Or perhaps overlapping circle graph / venn diagram (each circle being a product)?

Comment: this is a very interesting chart, had to draw it up on the whiteboard to understand how it will works. I don't think it will apply very well in this situation because the thing which draws the eyes on the graph is the color. In my situation, the color would be simply a product combination and the most important part, which is the count, would just be a number. 
I think I will be able to use it in my analysis, just not for this part.

Answer (score 1):

While it's nice to have an option to see a full matrix of possible combinations, as an addition to it, a matrix with a collapsible rows can be shown as well.

A high-level approximation presented below.

1. The initial state:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP2jbB.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

2. When a user presses the <kbd>+</kbd> button next to a row:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu72iF.png)</sup>

3. It expands, showing the combinations amount, that themselves can be expanded:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdAC4s.png)</sup>

Please note, that it is a general idea that should be evolved further for the needs of an effective representation considering what kind of analysis will be performed on the data.

Comment: I agree with your comments. I guess I was looking for something like a correlation plot or a heatmap. But maybe it does not fit this type of dataset. A drilldown table will be a good option, but probaly too much work for the type of insights we are looking to get out of this dataset. 
I will probably just stick with a simple table. Out of all the 32 combinations, it's very likely that only 3 or 4 would actually be of interest.